# Process.Start on second monitor without spamming the main monitor

Tags: c#, .net, user32

I'm hoping someone has an answer for me on this one. No matter what I try, I can't get the apps that I'm starting then snapping to a tableLayoutPanel1 to stop spamming the main monitor then moving to the second monitor and finally sizing to the panels. How can you force an exe to open on another monitor other than the primary monitor? I can't believe .NET has no way to do this without frantically trying to detect the window as fast as possible then move it.

Here's what I tried so far.

```
 Process vncProcess = new Process();
 vncProcess.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"VNCViewer.exe ");
 //vncProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-KeepAliveResponseTimeout=9999999 -UriSuppressConnectionPrompt=TRUE -Scaling=Fit -EnableToolbar=False " + ipAddress;
 vncProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-Monitor=" + devicename + "@ -KeepAliveResponseTimeout=9999999 -UriSuppressConnectionPrompt=TRUE -Scaling=Fit -EnableToolbar=False " + ipAddress;
 vncProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
 vncProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
 vncProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 vncProcess.Start(); // Start the process
 //vncProcess.WaitForInputIdle();

 vncProcesses.Add(vncProcess);

 // Function to check if the VNC Viewer's window title contains "LibVNCServer"
 Task<bool> IsWindowReadyWithTitle(Process process)
 {
     // Refresh the process info
     process.Refresh();
     // Check if the main window handle is ready and the title contains "LibVNCServer"
     return Task.FromResult(process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero && (process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("LibVNCServer") || process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("(10")));
     //|| process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("RealVNC")
 }

 while (!await IsWindowReadyWithTitle(vncProcess))
 {
     vncProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
     vncProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
     await Task.Delay(1); // Wait for 100ms before checking again


 }

    //ShowWindow(vncProcess.MainWindowHandle, SW_MINIMIZE);
    // Poll until the process has a window handle.

    //while (vncProcess.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    //{
    //    await Task.Delay(100); // Wait for 100ms before checking again.
    //    vncProcess.Refresh();
    //}
 
 MoveToMonitor(vncProcess.MainWindowHandle, monitorstart);
 // Adjust window style first
 int style = GetWindowLong(vncProcess.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
 style &= ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX;   // Disable minimize button
 style &= ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;   // Disable maximize button
 style &= ~WS_SYSMENU;       // Disable system menu (and close button)
 style &= ~WS_THICKFRAME;    // Disable resizable border
 style &= ~WS_CAPTION;       // Remove window caption
 style |= WS_CHILD;          // Ensure it's a child window
 SetWindowLong(vncProcess.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, style);

 //SetParent(vncProcess.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);


 // Now set VNC as a child of the panel
 SetParent(vncProcess.MainWindowHandle, vncPanel.Handle);

 vncProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

 // Resize event
 vncPanel.Resize += (sender, e) =>
 {
     if (vncProcess != null && !vncProcess.HasExited)
     {
         MoveWindow(vncProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, vncPanel.Width, vncPanel.Height, true);
     }
 };

 // Initial resize
 MoveWindow(vncProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, vncPanel.Width, vncPanel.Height, true);
```

Comment: Perhaps use a .net VNC implementation then you aren't starting an external exe but instead opening a form/window that you do have direct control of - https://github.com/marcin1990/dotnetvnc

Comment: The `ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle` value is really just a _hint_ (or rather: _a default_) that Windows uses unless the actual application insists on its own specific window placement and otherr options, so it's not .NET's (nor Windows') fault if the program you're wanting to run is intentionally overriding the `ProcessStartInfo`/`CreateProcessExW` options like that).

Comment: Your `IsWindowReadyWithTitle` function is not using `Task` correctly. Your calls to `MoveToMonitor` won't work if `vncProcess.MainWindowHandle` is not the actual `hWnd` you want to move. Also consider that your process might be limited by lack-of-HighDPI awareness.

Comment: You're calling a lot of functions that indicate error/status information via return values, but your program isn't checking those return values at all. That's sloppy and means that you're potentially (if not very likely) missing out on errors that might explain everything.

Comment: Repeatedly setting `ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle` _after_ the process has already started is exactly [what people say insanity is...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itjmKlYjUak)

Comment: Everything is working except for that flash of a black box before all the VNCviewers snap to the panels. I tried a .NET VNC but it doesn't show proper colours and I could not figure that out.

Comment: .Net nowadays also runs on Linux. You may end up in a tiling window manager ...